# How to say "rocket at launch"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

If I write "rocket at moment X", "rocket in assembly", "in flight", how do I say when it's about to be launched?

"At launch"? Sounds like "I eat rockets at lunch".

Comment: Do you just mean:  *On pad*? or do you mean precisely *at T minus 0*

Comment: I agree with Jim. *T-0*. Maybe *liftoff* or *blastoff*.

Comment: @Jim, yes, at T-0, but *on pad* works too.

Comment: Maybe "Rocket launch imminent"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the vehicle has been positioned and fueled, it is referred to as "[ready for launch.](http://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/imagegallery/image_feature_1871.html)"

The moments immediately *after* launch are typically referred to as "lift-off."

[Lift-off](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lift--off) - the vertical take-off of a spacecraft, rocket, or helicopter.